# Checking element has attr/class tagged dynamically or not in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

In `Angular2` is there a way for developer to check if the corresponding element of one component is tagged with some attribute/class or not?

Say we have below html:

```
<outer-controller>
    <label label-directive class='dynamically-set-class' dynamically-set-attribute>just some label</label>
</outer-controller>
```

The `label-directive` marked in the label element is a `Angular2` component, the two `dynamically-set-class` and `dynamically-set-attribute` are dynamically  controlled by the `outer-controller` basing on user input.

Every time the `outer-controller` reset the class of the label or the attribute, it fire a event that caught by `label-directive` and so the `label-directive` should do something dynamically base on the run-time attribute/class setting.

However, I cannot find any example in existing official `Angular2` doc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Input()` should do what you want:

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[label-directive]'
})
export class LabelDirective {
  @Input('class.dynamically-set-class') _dynamicallySetClass: boolean;
  @Input('dynamically-set-attribute') _dynamicallySetAttribute: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('class ' + _dynamicallySetClass);
    console.log('attribute ' + _dynamicallySetAttribute);
  }
  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    ..
  }
}
```

Comment: Just one more question, if in run-time the outer-controller changed the attribute/class, would the `@Input()` method reflected? Say the out-controller removed the `class.dynamically-set-class`, the `_dynamicallySetClass` would become `false`?

Comment: Yes, the value will be updated automatically and bindings from the template to the field would be udpated, `ngOnChanges()` would be called when the value changes. With `class.some-class` you can only check if a specific class is set or not set (`boolean`), but for arbitrary classes you can refer to class attribute directly (like to the attribute) `@Input('class') classes: String;` and check what classes are contained. (not sure it's a string, could be an array)

Comment: Just tried with your code, the `onChanges` method is working, however the two `@Input()` are not reflecting the actual value, both in `constructor` and `onChanges` method, they are `undefined`, while I can get the change in `onChanges` method, is it I can only monitor the change in `onChanges` method?

Comment: If you want to get notified about the changes and do something when the values change you can use `onChanges`. If you want to just read the values after the component is created use `ngOnInit() { ... }`. Using a getter/setter for `_dynamicallySetClass`/`_dynamicallySetAttribute` might work as well to execute code on value changes but I don't know TS well enough to provide code (I only use Dart myself).